# Find a counterexample that $f(x)$ is Gateaux differentiable and $\lambda(x)$ is not continous

Tags: gateaux-derivative

I've learned that function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$, at $x \in \mathbb {R}^n$, $f(x)$ is Gateaux differentiable, then exits a linear operator $\lambda (x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ such that $D_uf(x)=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(x+tu)-f(x)}{t}}=\lambda(x)(u),\forall u \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $\lambda(x)$ is continous, $f(x)$ is Frechet differentiable.

I want to find a counterexample that $f(x)$ is Gateaux differentiable and $\lambda(x)$ is linear, not continous, but it's hard for me, help me, thank you!

Comment: It's not a piece of Cake...

Comment: It's not the same, $\lambda(x)$ is linear and not continuos

Comment: If $ f $ is not Fréchet,  $\lambda $ is not continuous,  that's the  contrapositive of your own statement.

Comment: The Gateaux derivative is not necessarily linear.